# how to perform custom operations on an array to get a specific result in ruby using map or by using some enumerator functions?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array, `late_mark_array`:

```
["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]
```

These indicate an employee's consecutive "late marks" in a particular month. In this array `"yes"` indicates "late". `"no"` indicates "not late". I want to implement `penalties` for "lates".  To calculate penalties in above array:

- If there are three consecutive `"yes"` marks then I want to increment the `penalty` count by one.
- The penalty needs to be incremented by one for each consecutive `"yes"` following the initial 3.

Using this logic, the `penalty` to the above employee should be `"6"`.

for this i got the answer from stackoverflow below is the answer.

```
irb> input = ["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]
=> ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"]
irb> input.each_cons(3).count { |slice| slice.all? { |item| item == "yes" } }
=> 6
```

but now the requirement got changed. after the 3 late marks for (x) consecutive "yes", the penalty needs to be incremented by one. (here the x is the variable dynamically passed by the user.) how to change the above logic for this requirement?

Comment: What should the output be for the example input given the added requirement?

Comment: @jordan,  the above code gives "1" penalty for each consecutive "3" late marks(i mean three consecutive "yes"). and after the three consecutive "yes" again if there are any "yes" marks(it should come imeediately after "3" consecutive "yes"), then for each "yes",it increments  the penalty by one if it occurs after "3" yes. now i want to change the above logic where instead of each ("yes") mark, this is static in the above code. i want to pass here whatever the number i want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
def counter(arr)
 arr.each_slice(3).select {|c| c.count("yes") == 3}.count
end

def counter_penalty(my_arr)
  res=0
  3.times{|a| res+= counter(my_arr[a..-1])}
  res
end
counter_penalty(["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"])
```

You can found a way to do the times loop and each on an inliner but this will be better when you have to read this code again on the future.

Comment: I menctioned it as consecutive "3" where ever  the "3" is present, can i replace it whatever the dynamic value as i want, will that work?  what about the (X) value in this code? where can i replace the (x) value, even this is also, dynamic.

Comment: Yes should work if you give another parameter to counter_penalty(my_arr, num_repeats) and then changing 3.times by num_repeats.times.

Comment: it seams you did not understood my question compleately. there is one more dynamic value i want to pass(that is x.), apart from this "3". this indicates the number of occurrences of "yes", for which penalty needs to be incremented by one, after this consecutive "3" late marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def total_penalty(penalty_run_length, penalty_increment_length, late_mark_array)
  run_length = 0
  penalty = 1
  tot_penalty = 0
  late_mark_array.each do |s|
    if s == "yes"
      run_length += 1
      penalty += 1 if run_length >= penalty_increment_length
      tot_penalty += penalty if run_length >= penalty_run_length
    else
      run_length = 0
    end
  end
  tot_penalty
end

late_mark_array = ["yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes", "no",
                    "no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no"]

total_penalty(3, 5, late_mark_array) #=> 13
total_penalty(3, 4, late_mark_array) #=> 19
total_penalty(2, 3, late_mark_array) #=> 33
total_penalty(2, 2, late_mark_array) #=> 44 
total_penalty(1, 1, late_mark_array) #=> 65
```

You could write

```
late_mark_array.reduce(0) do |tot_penalty, s|
```

instead of

```
late_mark_array.each do |s|
```

but I see no advantage in doing so, as `tot_penalty` must be returned to `reduce` each iteration, whereas `tot_penalty` need only be returned at the end of the method if `each` is used.